# File reading in x86 assembly (NASM on DOS)

Tags: assembly, io, x86, nasm

So I'm writing a program in assembly that gets a file name from the user, opens the file, reads it, and prints the content to the screen. My goal is to eventually have it count the number of words in the file, but right now I just want it to read the content to verify that I'm doing all this correctly.

Here's my code (it's a lot, I know). I have not implemented the function for printing the screen yet:

```
[GLOBAL mystart]

[EXTERN _printf]
[EXTERN _atoi]

;define constants for buffer size and interupt
%define DOS 0f1h
%define INBUFFSIZE 40
%define FILEBUFFSIZE 4096

;define macro for printing on screen
%macro printLn 1
    mov ah, 09h
    mov edx, %1
    int DOS
%endmacro


[SECTION .text]

mystart:

readFile:
    ;prints "Enter the filename: " on screen
    printLn string

    ;takes filename from user
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov byte [infile], INBUFFSIZE
    mov byte [infile+1], 0
    mov edx, infile
    int DOS

    ;pads filename string with 0
    movzx ecx, byte [infile+1]
    mov byte [infile+ecx+2], 0

    ;opens the file (read mode)
    mov ah, 3Dh
    mov al, 0
    mov edx, infile+2
    int DOS
    mov [inhandle], ax
    jc failureJump

    ;reads the file
    mov ah, 3Fh
    mov bx, [inhandle]
    mov edx, filebuff
    mov cx, FILEBUFFSIZE
    int DOS
    jc failureJump
    printLn string3
    mov [nbytes], ax

    ;nbytes stores the number of bytes in the file, so that we can loop through it 
    ;prepare for looping through characters
    mov ecx, 0
    mov cl, [nbytes]
    mov ebx, 0

    ; I want to see how many bytes are in the file
    printLn ecx

processFile:
    printLn string4
    jmp endProcess
failureJump:
    printLn string2

endProcess:
    ret


[SECTION .data]
string db       "Enter a filename: ", 13, 10, '$'
string2 db      "Found a dot!", 13, 10, '$'
string3 db      "First break!", 13, 10, '$'
string4 db      "Second break!", 13, 10, '$'
string5 db      "Third break!", 13, 10, '$'

[SECTION .bss]
infile: resb 512
filebuff: resb FILEBUFFSIZE
inhandle: resw 1
nbytes: resw 1
nbytes2: resw 1
```

So as you can see, I have a couple break-strings and jc failureJumps in the code just to see where it's getting to. As it stands, the code does not work. Upon execution, it asks for the filename, but fails after first break, with a long error "Exiting due to signal SIGSEGV", among other things. It also mentions that the ecx register has the value ffffffff. If I comment out the "printLn ecx" line, the program seems to work (it gets to "Second break!"), though sluggishly, and I have no hard evidence that it is reading the file correctly (I do have a file for this: myfile.txt). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What planet are we on? `int 0F1h`? SIGSEGV? What output format are you getting from Nasm? Looks a little like "-f coff"(?)... DJGPP? Need more info!

Comment: That's correct, I use "nasm -f coff" to compile. Don't know what DJGPP is, I'm kind of a newbie :(

Comment: DJGPP is the mighty D. J. Delorie's port of GNU tools to 32-bit extended DOS.. Uses int 21h, not 0F1h, AFAIK I don't have much experience with it. In any case, printing a number by putting its value into `edx` is unlikely to work - `_printf` would be a better bet. Is your prompt even working with int 0F1h? If so, you're doing something right! Can you write back the buffer to see if you've read anything? I'd suggest ah=40h, ebx = 1, ecx = what the "read" returned, edx = buffer... int ???. Where did you get the idea to use int 0F1h? Does it work any better with int 21h? I'm still confused!

Comment: So I checked; yep, it's DJGPP. But no, int 21h is the interrupt in MASM.

Comment: I assure you that int 21h is for DOS - including DJGPP's extended DOS - got nothing to do with Masm! What happens if you change your define to 21h?

Comment: It prints strange characters; I think I even saw a smiley face in there...

Comment: A google for "DJGPP int 0F1h" finds a couple of examples - appears to be an alias for int 21h. A new one to me! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably that you define DOS as 0f1h. The correct value would be 21h.

Here is a list of DOS interrupts on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API#DOS_INT_21h_services

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's not a useful API reference because it doesn't tell you anything other than the function names (not even which other registers the args are in).  Ralph Brown's interrupt list (http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) is the canonical reference for 16-bit DOS/BIOS/PC stuff, apparently.